# Initializing an object using another object in Python

Tags: python, oop, methods

I have the following code:

```
import xmlrpc.client as xc
class AristaSwitch():
    def __init__(self,devicename,user='admin',password='xxxxxx')
        self.url="https://"+user+":"+password+"@"+devicename+"/command-api"
        self.Server = xc.Server(self.url)     **<----i know this is not correct** 
    more code below here
```

I would like to be able to write my code like below:

```
as = AristaSwitch("192.168.1.1")
as.runCmds(1, [ "show hostname" ] )
```

The way they do it is:

```
import xmlrpc.client as xc
switch = xc.Server( "https://admin:admin@172.16.130.16/command-api" ) 
response = switch.runCmds( 1, [ "show hostname" ] )
```

Update
 I think that adding this to the init function should do it

```
    self.InitializeRPCServer()
def InitializeRPCServer():
    switch=xc.Server(self.url)
    return switch
```

Comment: Presumably you mean `def __init__` in your class, not just `__init__`

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: and i am missing a : at the end of the def rule...

Comment: I don't see the problem at hand here. You clearly know how parameters work, so you can ask for the IP parameter (In the brackets I added) and then use that as the IP, and then it should work... Not that I am good at this. I hate parameters and I am just a hobbyist,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're just trying to wrap around `xc.Server`.  Just use a function instead of a class.

```
import xmlrpc.client as xc
def AristaSwitch(devicename, user='admin', password='xxxxxx'):
    url="https://"+user+":"+password+"@"+devicename+"/command-api"
    Server = xc.Server(url)
    return Server
```

Then just do your thing:

```
as = AristaSwitch("192.168.1.1")
as.runCmds(1, [ "show hostname" ] )
```

---

If you're talking about customizing the `xc.Server` object, you can just inherit it:

```
class AristaSwitch(xc.Server):
    def __init__(self, devicename, user='admin', password='xxxxxx'):
        self.url="https://"+user+":"+password+"@"+devicename+"/command-api"
        super().__init__(self.url)
```

You will need to update the `def __init__` to your customized `url` input, but you should be rather savvy about the original implementation since you might be inadvertently  overwriting some attributes or implementation details from the super class `xc.Server`.

With this use case, `AristaSwitch` is basically `xc.Server` with a customized instantiation method, and you can compliment it with your own methods later if you wish.

Comment: the point is to create an object that I can later improve and build on not just to run a simple function that will create an object

Comment: Yes that is the point ..to improve the object later and to hide the initial Server method. I want to make the class similar with other objects (other vendor REST API  were encapsulated similarly)

Comment: The function will in effect return the `xc.Server` object with a customized url for the instantiation.  It seems my answer is exactly what you're trying to achieve unless there's something fundamental I'm not understanding.   What kind of improvement are you thinking of? You might want to just inherit `xc.Server` into `AristaSwitch` in that case.

Comment: I want to be able to add more methods to the AristaSwitch later on. The way you suggest I should do it creates an RPC server object not a switch object that has the runCmds method among other methods

Comment: Okay, see my edited answer (second part), it might be more of what you're thinking of.

Comment: I knew I could do that, I was just wondering if it is possible to somehow embed the entire server object within the switch object. I guess this is what you mean above with rewriting methods.

Comment: I'd wager class inheritance is what you're looking for, since `AristaSwitch` become the de-facto customized `xc.Server` object that you wanted to tailor to your needs.  Otherwise you will be need to call `AristaSwitch.Server._some_server_method` instead of `AristaSwitch._some_server_method` if you were to have `xc.Server` as an object within your custom `class`.  Once you inherit the super class, all the super's method is known and accessible to the inherited class (short for those you might be replacing).